# Mysql Sum using ranking (best x scores from all rounds for all players)

Tags: mysql, sum, limit

1. Some help please.  I have tested many examples in this forum without success.

This script works fine but I now wish to limit the summed round scores to best 14 rounds.

```
SELECT 
RoundScoreCard.idPlayerDetails as ID,
#concat(PlayerFirstName," ",PlayerLastName)as Name,
sum(RoundScoreCardPlayerPoints) as Total 

from RoundScoreCard 

join PlayerDetails on RoundScoreCard.idPlayerDetails = PlayerDetails.idplayerdetails 
group by RoundScoreCard.idPlayerDetails 
order by Total DESC
```

Test with this single sub query works fine;

```
select sum(RoundScoreCardPlayerPoints) 
FROM 
(select RoundScoreCardPlayerPoints
from RoundScoreCard
where RoundScoreCard.idPlayerDetails = @player 
order by RoundScoreCardPlayerPoints desc 
limit 14) as subquery
;
```

Have battled for about a week modifying every example I can find but just cant get this to work listing all players.  I can show a multitude of attempts but this would confuse this question for others.
(I do have a solution using a test for records and then an IF statement but it seems excessive and costly on time.)

2. Also; out of interest, is it possible to have multiple limit statements?  i.e. what if I only wanted the top 3 players with their best 14 results from all the rounds?

Example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f393a6/3

All the best for the new year.

---

OK - so I have progressed a bit further with the help of this article; https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/selecting-the-top-n-results-by-group-in-mysql.html

Thanks [Rob Gravelle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4245323/rob-gravelle)

Limiting my top scores to 2 for each player

My Sql is now as follows:

```
Select idRoundScorecard, RoundScoreCardPlayerPoints,idPlayerDetails
 FROM
 (
   SELECT idRoundScorecard, RoundScoreCardPlayerPoints, idPlayerDetails,
   @player_score_rank := IF(@current_player = idPlayerDetails, 
                         @player_score_rank + 1, 
                         1
                      ) AS player_score_rank,
   @current_player := idPlayerDetails
   FROM RoundScoreCard
    ORDER BY idPlayerDetails, RoundScoreCardPlayerPoints DESC
 ) ranked
 WHERE player_score_rank <= 2;
```

Now I have to sum and rank again?

Comment: Add a rank window function to the scorecard query, let the subquery select only those with rank below 15.

Comment: Select top 14 results for each user, calculate sums, then select top 3 players.

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the note.  This might help  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f393a6/2.  Not to sure how sqlfiddle works.  Is anyone able to modify?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - thanks for the tip.  Took me a long time to get my head around the ranking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f4fe7/9

```
select idPlayerDetails as ID, concat(PlayerFirstName," ",PlayerLastName)as Name,sum(Points) as Points
from
(Select idRoundScorecard, RoundScoreCardPlayerPoints as Points,idPlayerDetails
 FROM
 (SELECT idRoundScorecard, RoundScoreCardPlayerPoints, idPlayerDetails,
   @player_rank := IF(@current_player = idPlayerDetails, 
                         @player_rank + 1, 
                         1
                      ) AS player_rank,
   @current_player := idPlayerDetails
   FROM RoundScoreCard
    ORDER BY idPlayerDetails, RoundScoreCardPlayerPoints DESC
 ) ranked
 WHERE player_rank <= 5 )summed
natural join PlayerDetails
group by idPlayerDetails
order by Points desc
 ;
```

Comment: Current versions of mysql and mariadb have a rank() function, and row_number() to answer your problem.  See my answer.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Yes that would make life easier but the cloud server I have to use is on version 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong with rank(), it needed row_number()

```
With scores as (
  SELEct
RoundScoreCard.idPlayerDetails as ID,
RoundScoreCardPlayerPoints As pts,
Dense_rank() Over (Partition by idPlayerDetails
            Order by RoundScoreCardPlayerPoints  Desc) As rK,
Row_number() Over (Partition by idPlayerDetails
            Order by RoundScoreCardPlayerPoints  Desc) As rn
from RoundScoreCard 
)
select id, sum(pts) from scores
Where rn < 3
group by id;
```

Gives the sum of the best two rounds.

see [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ck9upeDzjrCaUG4maL93kH/0)